# Log-log lmplot with seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

Can Seaborn's `lmplot` plot on log-log scale?

This is lmplot with linear axes:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
x =  10**arange(1, 10)
y = 10** arange(1,10)*2
df1 = pd.DataFrame( data=y, index=x )
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'x': x, 'y': y}) 
sns.lmplot('x', 'y', df2)
```

![sns.lmplot('x', 'y', df2)][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXbtg.png

Comment: If you're not using facets, it will be easier to use `seaborn.regplot`.

Comment: I'm a little confused because your code draws two plots. Are you trying to reproduce the first plot with seaborn? Or do you want to draw the `lmplot` on top of the first plot?

Comment: @mwaskom the first plot should not be there. I remove it now from the code.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If you just want to plot a simple regression, it will be easier to use `seaborn.regplot`. This seems to work (although I'm not sure where the y axis minor grid goes)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = 10 ** np.arange(1, 10)
y = x * 2
data = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': x, 'y': y})

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
ax.set(xscale="log", yscale="log")
sns.regplot("x", "y", data, ax=ax, scatter_kws={"s": 100})
```

[image]

If you need to use `lmplot` for other purposes, this is what comes to mind, but I'm not sure what's happening with the x axis ticks. If someone has ideas and it's a bug in seaborn, I'm happy to fix it:

```
grid = sns.lmplot('x', 'y', data, size=7, truncate=True, scatter_kws={"s": 100})
grid.set(xscale="log", yscale="log")
```

[image]

Comment: I get the following error using this code: `ValueError: posx and posy should be finite values`.

Comment: What is the deal with all (the wrong placing of) the white lines?

Comment: @borgr what do you mean by wrong? each line represents a multiple:  2 * 10^p, 4 * 10^p ... for all even numbers between 2 and 10

Comment: So you have lines by non log plot and a logplot, depends on the context, but it might be confusing

Answer (score 13):

The simplest way to make a log-log plot from (probably) any seaborn plot is:

```
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
```

In the example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
x =  10**np.arange(1, 10)
y = 10** np.arange(1,10)*2
df1 = pd.DataFrame( data=y, index=x )
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'x': x, 'y': y}) 
sns.lmplot('x', 'y', df2)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
```

[image: Link to resulting image]

Answer (score 6):

Call the seaborn function first. It returns a `FacetGrid` object which has an `axes` attribute (a 2-d numpy array of matplotlib `Axes`). Grab the `Axes` object and pass that to the call to `df1.plot`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

x =  10**np.arange(1, 10)
y = 10**np.arange(1,10)*2
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=y, index=x)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'x': x, 'y': y})

fgrid = sns.lmplot('x', 'y', df2)    
ax = fgrid.axes[0][0]
df1.plot(ax=ax)        

ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

Comment: In theory it should be simpler, and you could just do `fgrid.set(xscale="log", yscale="log")`, but due to a combination of some matplotlib weirdness and the way `lmplot` works this doesn't quite get what we want.

Comment: thanks for chiming in @mwaskom. I'm seeing the weirdness you describe with my example too.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, without explicit usage of *matplotlib*, use the `subplot_kws` argument in the `facet_kws` argument of the plot function.

From the *seaborn* documentation https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html

> facet_kws: dict
>
> Dictionary of keyword arguments for FacetGrid.

Example:  `facet_kws={"subplot_kws": {"yscale": "log"}}` for a *y-axis* in *log-scale*.
Of course, be sure data processed is positive.