# y-axis scaling in seaborn vs pandas

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm plotting a scatter plot using a `pandas` dataframe. This works correctly, but I wanted to use `seaborn` themes and specials functions. When I plot the same data points calling seaborn, the y-axis remains almost invisible. X-axis values ranges from `5000-15000`, while y-axis values are in `[-6:6]*10^-7`.

If I multiply the y-axis values by 10^6, they display correctly, but the actual values when plotted using `seaborn` remains invisible/indistinguishable in a `seaborn` generated plot.

How can I `seaborn` so that the y-axis values scale automatically in the resultant plot?

Also some rows even contain `NaN`, not in this case, how to disregard that while plotting, short of manually weeding out rows containing `NaN`.

Below is the code I've used to plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv("datascale.csv")
subdf = df.loc[(df.types == "easy") & (df.weight > 1300), ]

subdf = subdf.iloc[1:61, ]
subdf.drop(subdf.index[[25]], inplace=True) #row containing NaN

subdf.plot(x='length', y='speed', style='s') #scales y-axis correctly

sns.lmplot("length", "speed", data=subdf, fit_reg=True, lowess=True) #doesn't scale y-axis properly

# multiplying by 10^6 displays the plot correctly, in matplotlib
plt.scatter(subdf['length'], 10**6*subdf['speed'])
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the y axis remains invisible", and it's not possible to run your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange that seaborn does not scale the axis correctly. Nonetheless, you can correct this behaviour. First, get a reference to the axis object of the plot:

```
lm = sns.lmplot("length", "speed", data=subdf, fit_reg=True)
```

After that you can manually set the y-axis limits:

```
lm.axes[0,0].set_ylim(min(subdf.speed), max(subdf.speed))
```

The result should look something like this:

[image]

Example Jupyter notebook [here](https://gist.github.com/markusschanta/d3adaa508496e82e13e7a20f94b703bc).

Comment: @mwaskom this answer addresses the issue I was facing, values being too small, seems to become almost invisible.

Comment: Markus how do I display the final plot with axes limits corrected? I'm using Spyder, and the prompt doesn't update or draw the new plot. I'm new to python business, not sure how to display the updated plot.

Answer (score 0):

Seaborn and matplotlib should just ignore NaN values when plotting.  You should be able to leave them as is.

As for the y scaling: there might be a bug in seaborn.

The most basic workaround is still to scale the data before plotting.
Scale to microspeed in the dataframe before plotting and plot microspeed instead.

```
subdf['microspeed']=subdf['speed']*10**6
```

Or transform to log y before plotting, i.e.

```
import math
df = pd.DataFrame({'speed':[1, 100, 10**-6]})
df['logspeed'] = df['speed'].map(lambda x: math.log(x,10))
```

then plot logspeed instead of speed.

Another approach would be to use seaborn regplot [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23918246/1134881).

Matplot lib correctly scales and plots for me as follows:

```
plt.plot(subdf['length'], subdf['speed'], 'o')
```

Comment: But that loses the information, I get log values instead of normal values and that skews the scale/relative values. Also lowess fit is just an after-thought, mostly I'm trying to get a scatter plot.

Comment: How can I replicate what I can achieve though `pandas` interface to `matplotlib`, but with `seaborn` ?

Comment: Edited answer to include matplotlib solution.