# How to use log scale for the axes of a seaborn relplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I tried drawing a relplot with log scaled axes.
Making use of previous [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913151/log-log-lmplot-with-seaborn), I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
ax.set(xscale="log", yscale="log")

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.relplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue='smoker', data=tips)
plt.show()
```

However the axes were not changed in the result.

[image]

How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scatterplot` and dont forget to mention your `axes` in your plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax.set(xscale="log", yscale="log")
sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue='smoker', data=tips,ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

**Edit** - `relplot` is a figure-level function and does not accept the `ax= paramter`

Comment: Great, thanks!
Any idea why it didn't work for `relplot`?

Answer (score 20):

For `sns.relplot` you can set the scale as follows:

```
g = sns.relplot(...)
g.set(xscale="log")
g.set(yscale="log")
```

This will set the scales for all sub-graphs.